# Rename all files with the name pattern *.[a-z0-9].bundle.*, to replace the [a-z0-9] with a given string

Tags: bash, shell, glob, file-rename, angular2-cli

On building apps with the Angular 2 CLI, I get outputs which are named, for instance:

```
inline.d41d8cd.bundle.js
main.6d2e2e89.bundle.js
```

etc.

What I'm looking to do is create a bash script to rename the files, replacing the digits between the first two `.` with some given generic string.  Tried a few things, including sed, but I couldn't get them to work. Can anyone suggest a bash script to get this working?

Comment: Try command `rename`: `rename 's/\.\X{4,8}\./.myString./' *.js`

Comment: I will give that a try, thanks!

Comment: @OliverRadini, do you want to replace Bash strings, or filenames on the file system?

Comment: filenames, sorry I ought ot have been more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pure-bash option:

```
shopt -s extglob    # so *(...) will work
generic_string="foo"   # or whatever else you want between the dots
for f in *.bundle.js ; do
    mv -vi "$f" "${f/.*([^.])./.${generic_string}.}"
done
```

The key is the replacement `${f/.*([^.]./.${generic_string}.}`.  The pattern `/.*([^.])./` matches the first occurrence of `.<some text>.`, where `<some text>` does not include a dot (`[^.]`) (see the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)).  The replacement `.${generic_string}.` replaces that with whatever generic string you want.  Other than that, double-quote in case you have spaces, and there you are!

**Edit** Thanks to F. Hauri - added `-vi` to `mv`.  `-v` = show what is being renamed; `-i` = prompt before overwrite ([man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mv)).

Comment: worked fantastically, only amend was to replace `*.bundle.js` with `*.bundle.*`, sorry if I wasn't specific enough¬

Comment: @OliverRadini Glad to help!

Comment: `-i` switch could prevent bad behaviour

Answer (score 2):

In pure `bash` `regEx` using the `=~` variable (supported from `bash 3.0` onwards)

```
#!/bin/bash

string_to_replace_with="sample"

for file in *.js
do
    [[ $file =~ \.([[:alnum:]]+).*$ ]] && string="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" 
    mv -v "$file" "${file/$string/$string_to_replace_with}"
done
```

For your given input files, running the script

```
$ bash script.sh
inline.d41d8cd.bundle.js -> inline.sample.bundle.js
main.6d2e2e89.bundle.js -> main.sample.bundle.js
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, I haven't got time to check if this works right now, but appreciate the time to answer

Answer (score 2):

Short, powerfull and efficient:

Use this ([perl](/questions/tagged/perl)) tool. And use *Perl Regular Expression*:

```
rename 's/\.\X{4,8}\./.myString./' *.js
```

or

```
rename 's/\.\X+\./.myString./' *.js
```

Comment: Is this the util-linux rename or a different rename?  The man page for util-linux rename(1) on my cygwin install lists the expression and replacement as separate parameters, rather than combined in an `s///`.

Comment: Util-linux `rename` is a `C` rewritten from original [tag:perl] `rename` command. It must work with *PCRE* (*Perl Common Regular Expression*)